# stringstream code separating words - how does this thing work? code snippet inside

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, stringstream

i have this code i found to cut a string into words.
i cant figure out how the while part works. how does it know to extract words without whitespaces to the buf variable?
it seems the extraction operator (>>) is used both to progress bits into the buffer, and to return true for the loop - i just cant figure out how it knows to cut the words by whitespaces.

```
string buf; // Have a buffer string
stringstream ss(str); // Insert the string into a stream

vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold our words

while (ss >> buf)
    tokens.push_back(buf);
```

Comment: Hm... operator >> is called on stringstream which copies a stream of bytes until the first whitespace, and that is done in a loop?

Comment: i understand what it does, no need to translate it for me. i just wonder, how? in the link i got from the answer below, it seems >> can recognize some conditions, but none mention a whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [`std::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt), not the bitwise operator, and is used to extract formatted data, in this case a `std::string`. It returns a reference to the stream being read.

A `stringstream` can be used in a boolean context due to its conversion [`operator void*()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), allowing it to be used as the terminating condition in the loop.

Comment: thank you for your comment. it is not the operator i thought it is indeed. also the boolean context makes sense now. but where does it say about whitespaces? just curious to understand how that thing works, im a c++ newbie :)

Comment: That `operator void*` is actually `operator bool` in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

> i just cant figure out how it knows to cut the words by whitespaces

Since the type of `buf` is `std::string`, you need to read the description of `operator>>` that takes an `std::istream` on the left and a `std::string` on the right.

To quote [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

> Characters are extracted and appended onto `str` until either:
>
> `N` characters are read, where `N` is `is.width()` if `is.width() > 0`, otherwise `N` is `str.max_size()`,
>
> an EOF marker is read from `is`, or
>
> `isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next character in `is`.

That last clause says, in English, "stop if the next character is a space"

Comment: yep, hmjd also fixed his link to that page, i understand it now. thank you as well :)

Comment: come to think of it, that page is missing some information, editing.